# Retrieving PCDATA xpath via the c++ pugixml library

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, pugixml

I spent the last week reading and re-reading the pugixml documentation and I can find no method of retrieving the PCDATA with xpath.

Please explain would I pull the text from title:

```
<html><head><title>Hello!</title></head></html>
```

Last time I asked this question the only answers I got referred to generic xpath queries, rather than specifically to the pugixml library functions. I've read the xpath documentation thoroughly, so don't worry about educating me about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* text = doc.select_single_node("html/head/title/text()").node().value();
```

- `select_single_node` selects the PCDATA node
- `.node()` converts from xpath_node to xml_node (this is necessary since XPath nodes are either xml nodes or attributes)
- `.value()` gets the value of the node (i.e. text).

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I was fetching PCDATA i first found the node, and after that I called

```
node = retrive_xml_node_from_xpath();
node.first_child().value;
```

So for the example you show create an xpath to find the title node, and then get its first childs value.